# React Hook Order Error - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - How do you troubleshoot this?

Tags: reactjs

I have used React Material UI's responsive sidebar, then seperated out the populating of the drawer, icon selection, and building the nested lists to seperate functions. Everything is working as expected, resize the page the the draw comes in, all links and navigation working great.

There is a button on the toolbar that onclick will retract the draw, that is now giving me a hook order error. I suspect its because I have dozens of nested functions.

How do I even go about troubleshooting this? How can I find out which hook, or where is actually causing the issue? Is there some way to step by step see each hook call as it happens so I can see exactly what line of code is cause the out of ordering?

Is this hook order driving anyone else mad? and making them hate hooks or just me?

Comment: Can you provide any code that demonstrates the issue with a minimal example? That said, this error is a generic error that shouldn't have anything to do with hooks per se. Look at the line your error indicates is an error. Whatever you're trying to access the length property on is `undefined` when you don't expect it to be.

Comment: The length its refering too is the length of the hook array. Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Layout. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: 

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useState                   useState
2. useContext                 useContext
3. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
4. useContext                 useContext
5. useRef                     useRef

Comment: I have put together a few simplified examples and all work. Which is the issue Im having, I have no i doubt i have caused the issue, but I have no idea how to step through and find where. There are so many hooks being called by the React Material UI library internally it could be any one of them.

Comment: Did you read the "Rules of Hooks" referenced in the error? (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Your description (dozens of nested functions) implies to me that this could be the cause. If you are using ESlint, try adding the `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` plugin. It might better point out the issue.

Comment: I did, Im not seeing any issues it described. I am using create-react-app > v3 so that eslint is already included. I did try running it myself directly, but it doesn't identify any issues with the code. I have tried methodically removing all the react hooks from the code, but there always seems to be more somewhere in the material ui library. I think perhaps i need to move away from using Material UI React and us something like Bootstrap.

Comment: If you have the code somewhere, I can take a look. Moving to a different UI framework seems pretty heavy handed, and since it sounds React specific, I doubt going to Bootstrap would really solve your problem unless it simplifies things that you're trying to work around in some complex way with MUI (and that complex workaround is the source of the problem)

Comment: Thanks appreciate the offer. I isolated the issue to two components, by merging them back together the issue went away. There is no hooks I added, only the hooks in the Material React UI Library. It would be really nice to have a way to pin point which hook changed, which one caused the issue, or which calling line triggered an issue. Without line by line removing/adding back I don't know how else to debug. Now its a smaller amount of code ill make a sandbox, perhaps knowing what caused the issue will help me not repeat it.